# Android studio getting warning for support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting error in **build.gradle** file

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).
```

Here is my gradle file

```
android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.pristology.mysociety"
                minSdkVersion 15
                targetSdkVersion 28
                versionCode 3
                versionName "1.0.3"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

            implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

I am getting warning in app level gradle file when update android studio 3.3.2

Comment: You should add your `gradle` file

Comment: post your dependencies portion from build.gradle

Comment: share your app level gradle file

Comment: I have added my gradle file

Comment: this issue occurs when your library uses different appcompat version.

Answer (score 2):

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

It happens because some of your libraries use an old version `support-media-compat`.

Just add explicitly the version of the library in your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

1st)  you are getting problem because of different appcompat version so change your 
dependency because in gradle version 3.+ it causes problem

```
> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

to this version

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'-alpha1`

or you can use v7:27.1.1 but you have to change it everywhere in app:gradle

2nd) if you are using firebase then it will also cause problem so remove this line of code

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'`

because this line isn't necessary and u will get rid of this problem ;)

Comment: Firebase isn't the problem. Downgrading support library is never advised; it breaks functionality/stability of app. Always use latest stable version of libraries. Never downgrade, there's valid reason why newer version to the library is made. New versions have bugfixes & added features. See the difference of version code: https://android.jlelse.eu/what-is-the-difference-between-canary-beta-rc-and-stable-releases-in-the-android-studio-bbbb77e7c3cf & https://medium.com/@maxirosson/versioning-android-apps-d6ec171cfd82 & https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions

Comment: if you use firebase then that line which i mention is also responsible for this problem if u used firebase ever then u must know and downgrade library causes problem but appcompat-v7:28.0.0 has bugs thats why i suggest appcompat-v7:28.0.0'-alpha1 and appcompat-v7:27.1.1 is for backup plan because it is fixed version and has no bugs

Comment: Suggest an alpha (and previous!) release instead of stable release in general is never a good tip.